# oracle sql query hangs

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Alright so what I'm trying to do with the last 2 columns here:  Each ticket has a journal associated with it that can have multiple entries.  I am trying to get the latest entry given a ticket number and based on the time stamp associated with the entry, create a query that shows how much time has elapsed since that last entry. The last column shows elapsed time as well, but for a specific type of journal entry.
Entries into this query need to be restricted to tickets that have an owner ID that correspond to 1 of 2 people.  In this example, those people are 'aaaa cccc' and 'bbbb dddd'. So, when I run the query, it just hangs.  Also, when I remove the last 2 columns, it still hangs, so I assume it has something to do with the where statement.  I'm at a loss here, but since I'm quite new to sql, there could be something simple I'm missing.

```
SELECT t.ticket_id, 
   cct.issue, 
   t.status, 
   t.priority, 
   a.account_name, 
   o.identifier, 
   To_char(t.created, 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss')   AS  "CREATED", 
   To_char(SYSDATE - (SELECT Max(ti.timestamp) 
                      FROM   ticket_journal ti 
                      WHERE  ti.ticket_id = t.ticket_id), 'hh:mm:ss') AS "LAST_ENTRY", 
   To_char(SYSDATE - (SELECT Max(ti.timestamp) 
                      FROM   ticket_journal ti 
                      WHERE  ti.ticket_id = t.ticket_id 
                             AND ( ti.journal_type LIKE 'External' 
                                    OR ti.journal_type LIKE 'External/WIP' 
                                 )), 'hh:mm:ss')                   AS "LAST_EXT_ENTRY" 
FROM   tickets t, 
   customer_care_tickets cct, 
   accounts a, 
   orders o 
WHERE  t.owner IN (SELECT cont.contact_id 
                   FROM   contacts cont 
                   WHERE  ( cont.first_name LIKE 'aaaa' 
                          OR cont.first_name LIKE 'bbbb' ) 
                   AND ( cont.last_name LIKE 'cccc' 
                        OR cont.last_name LIKE 'dddd' ))
```

Comment: I don't see any join conditions. How do you connect those 4 tables together?

Comment: It appears that you are doing a Cartesian join between 4 tables.  That will probably blow out your `TEMP` tablespace before it finally dies.  I'm assuming that there are keys that allow you to relate the data in the various tables together.  You'd need to specify those join criteria in the `WHERE` clause (or move to using the explicit join syntax)

Comment: Given that there are no wildcard characters in the LIKE comparisons you might as well just use `=` instead of LIKE.  Or add wildcards, as in `cont.first_name LIKE '%aaaa%'` if you want to find rows where FIRST_NAME contains the characters `aaaa`.  Documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/html/A85397_01/operator.htm). Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you may have a cartesian join here. http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Cartesian_join

I'm not sure exactly how your database keys are constructed so I just guessed below, but it may give you an idea of how you need to link your tables.  These are ANSI joins, not Oracle-specific.  I recommend you learn to use these types of joins so your code is more portable.  I hope this helps.

For outer joins use FULL JOIN for inner joins use JOIN or INNER JOIN.  For left/right joins use LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN.

```
FROM tickets t
   JOIN customer_care_tickets cct ON t.ticket_id = cct.ticket_id
   JOIN accounts a ON cct.account_id = a.account_id
   JOIN orders o ON o.ticket_id = t.ticket_id
WHERE  t.owner IN (SELECT cont.contact_id 
                   FROM   contacts cont 
                   WHERE  ( cont.first_name LIKE 'aaaa' 
                          OR cont.first_name LIKE 'bbbb' ) 
                   AND ( cont.last_name LIKE 'cccc' 
                        OR cont.last_name LIKE 'dddd' ))
```

Comment: The IN clause would select IDs for contacts called 'aaaa dddd' and 'bbbb cccc', which is not desirable but not actually the cause of the OP's hanging problem.

Comment: Although I think Mr bbbb cccc was a character in [Bradbury's Martian Chronicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Martian_Chronicles)

Comment: or aaaa cccc and bbbb dddd, can't leave those poor guys out.

Comment: Those are the guys the OP *wants* to include.  My point is, the query as it stands does not restrict the result set to just the rows the OP needs.

Comment: Alright this does indeed seem to work for my purposes.  I had to take out to_char because it couldn't convert and I'm not yet sure the numbers it puts out make much sense, but that's another issue entirely.  For the record, I used:
    
    join customer_care_tickets cct on t.ticket_id=cct.ticket_id
    join accounts a on t.account_id=a.account_id
    join orders o on o.account_id=t.account_id

Comment: Please mark the question as answered if the solution suited your needs.

Comment: Also, APC lets just say that one of the names that I'm searching for is so unique (ie not an actual name) that they will never be found in reverse formation.